# Yii2 Combine dropdown val with kartik typeahead

Tags: php, yii2, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I would like to combine a dropdown select for Country with an ajax populated Typeahead for State but I am struggling. I am using  kartik's typeahead widget for Yii2 I have tried to destroy the instance and recreate it however it's not populating with data see below.

```
<?php //country field
                $datacountry = \app\helper\countries::getCountries();
                echo $form->field($client, 'country')->dropDownList($datacountry, ['prompt' => '-Choose a Country-',
                    'onchange' => '$("#county").val("");
            $.post( "' . Url::to(['/state-search?country=']) . '"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
               $("#county").typeahead("destroy");                 
                $("#county").typeahead({local: JSON.parse(data)});

            });
        ']);
                ?>
<?php


                echo $form->field($client, 'county')->widget(kartik\typeahead\Typeahead::className(), [

                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Filter as you type ...','id'=>'county'],
                    'dataset' => [
                        [
                            'local' => [''],
                            'limit' => 10,

                            'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                            'cache' => false,
                            'display' => 'value',
                            'templates' => [
'suggestion' => new JsExpression("Handlebars.compile('{$template}')")
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],                        
                ]);
                    ?>
```

Alternatively can I pass a js variable into the remote api for bloodhound?

```
 'remote' => [
                                    'url' => Url::to(['county-search']) . '?q=%QUERY',
                                    'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                                ],
```

e.g

```
 new JsExpression('$("#client-country").val()')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should use [select2](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2) widget? There you can see some demos http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Comment: Unfortunately you can't free type in a select and can only select from the predefined options.